# Performance issue using MemberQ inside Table

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a list of positions that I would like to use in an array. I came up with the following code to fill a Table with 'ones' in these positions, and 'zeros' everywhere else:

```
positions = RandomInteger[{1, 200}, {2000, 2}];
array = Table[If[MemberQ[positions, {i, j}], 1, 0], {i, 1, 200}, {j, 1, 200}];
```

Maybe this is not the most efficient way to solve this, but it works fast enough for me (around 0.15 seconds).

My problem arose when I assigned the table dimensions in an earlier statement:

```
dimx = 200;
dimy = 200;
array = Table[If[MemberQ[positions, {i, j}], 1, 0], {i, 1, dimx}, {j, 1, dimy}];
```

The code above takes around 22 seconds to execute on my machine, while the only change is that I put `dimx` and `dimy` as table dimensions, instead of 200 directly.

I was hoping someone could explain to me why this is happening and if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: Take a look at `SparseArray`

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, you can force evaluation of the table iterators, i.e. `Evaluate@{i, 1, dimx}, Evaluate@{j, 1, dimy}`. This will bring the timing in the second piece of code in line with the first. I vaguely suspect that this might have something to do with autocompilation within `Table`; autocompilation may be triggered when `Table`, which is a `HoldAll` function, can "see" the explicit size of the array being produced, but not when the size is "hidden" within the symbols `dimx` and `dimy`. Unfortunately I am unable to go into more detail right this moment.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for this quick fix!

Comment: As @LukasLang already mentioned, `SparseArray` does a good job here: `SparseArray[positions -> 1, {dimx, dimy}, 0]`

Comment: @LukasLang and HenrikSchumacher Thank you, your solution instantly does exactly what I needed, so my problem is solved!

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have indicated how to redress this but I will point out that one can improve on the `MemberQ` speed here. The idea is to create a lookup table for the positions of interest, using pattern-free down values. This is fast to create:

```
positions = RandomInteger[{1, 200}, {2000, 2}];
AbsoluteTiming[Scan[(presentQ[#] = True) &, positions];]

(* Out[44]= {0.005684, Null} *)
```

And the run time is quite good:

```
dimx = 200;
dimy = 200;
AbsoluteTiming[
 array = Table[
    If[MemberQ[positions, {i, j}], 1, 0], {i, 1, dimx}, {j, 1, dimy}];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 array2 = Table[
    If[TrueQ[presentQ[{i, j}]], 1, 0], {i, 1, dimx}, {j, 1, dimy}];]
array === array2

(* Out[55]= {13.410903, Null}

Out[56]= {0.033746, Null}

Out[57]= True *)
```

One can also get good efficiency using `Dispatch`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[repRules = Dispatch[Thread[positions -> 1]];]

(* Out[62]= {0.002518, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 array3 = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, dimx}, {j, 1, dimy}] /. 
     repRules /. {i_Integer, j_Integer} -> 0;]
array3 === array2

(* Out[63]= {0.057041, Null}

Out[64]= True *)
```

Another possibility, which I did not try, would use `Association` with the elements in `positions` as keys.

Comment: "And the run time is quite good". I made a custom set data structure for integers with LibraryLink, with a "memberQ" operation.  Pattern-free downvalues are actually faster when testing membership one-by-one. (Of course, for batch testing, the C++ solution will be faster.)  `Association` could be even better because it can do batch processing with Lookup directly in Mathematica, e.g. `at = AssociationThread[members -> True]` then `Lookup[at, elements, False]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs One possibility for testing a set quickly is to use `Nearest` (create if on `positions`, run the `NearestFunction` on the full array). Replace exact hits with 1 and all else with 0. Your `Association`/`LookUp` method might be better though.